# Как исправить Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу понять что не нравится браузеру в 12-ой и скорее всего 14-ой строке.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Таблица</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var x = 10;
        var y = 10;
        function DrawTable(){
            var result;
            result = "<table>";
            for (var i = 0, i < x, i++){
                result += "<tr>";
                for (var j = 0, j < x, j++){
                    result += "<td>" + i * j + "</td>";
                }
                result += "</tr>";
            }
            result += "</table>";
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            table.innerHTML = result;
            console.log(result);
        }
    </script>
    <button onclick = DrawTable()>Таблица</button>
    <div id = "table">
    </div>
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <table border = "1" cellpadding = "10">
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <h2>2</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: 1. Условия в цикле надо писать через точку с запятой а не черезз апятую.
2. onclick надо вешать саму функцию а не результат исполнения,причем надо в кавычках

Comment: спасибо, я еще только учусь) про точку запятой в условиях цикла не знал почему то даже